# Applications of Ambrose-Singer theorem on holonomy

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, big-list, connections, holonomy

I am planning to introduce to a group of Graduate students the  notion of connections on Principal bundle, curvature of connection, Holonomy.  I want to conclude with the statement of Ambrose-Singer theorem which is as follows.

> Let $P(M,G)$ be a Principal bundle where $M$ is connected and paracompact. Let $\Gamma$ be a connection in $P$, $\Omega$ the curvature form, $\Phi(u)$ the holonomy group with reference point $u\in P$ and $P(u)$ the holonomy bundle through $u$ of $\Gamma$. Then the Lie algebra of holonomy group $\Phi(u)$  is equal to the subspace of $\mathfrak{g}$, Lie algebra of $G$, generated by all elements of the form $\Omega_v(X,Y)$ where $v\in P(u)$ and $X$ and $Y$ are arbitrary horizantal vectors at $v$.

I am not planning to prove the theorem but just state it. It looks beautiful in itself but, if I can say some applications of this theorem, it would bring out the power of this theorem.

Can you suggest some applications of this Ambrose-Singer theorem on Holonomy.

Comment: One result in one answer please.

Comment: Use Google Scholar to search for citations to the Ambrose-Singer paper? I don't know any off-hand, so that is one thing I would do. Also, if you are wanting a list, with no one correct answer, the community norms here is that this question should probably be converted to CW.

Comment: I find many hits here: https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=13701757514937985358

Comment: @DavidRoberts I was thinking it is better if someone who already has experience give a crux of where this can be/is used than checking google...

Comment: I found https://arxiv.org/abs/1007.3543 which refers to a generalisation of Ambrose-Singer that helps understand the KP hierarchy (http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Kadomtsev-Petviashvili_equation) and there seems to be a bunch of integrable systems work that uses the theorem.

Comment: The classification of holonomy (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonomy#The_Berger_classification) is _the_ big important application, according to a colleague who is a Riemannian geometer.

Comment: @DavidRoberts I am not familiar with integrable systems and all but I am very much interested in knowing about that Berger classification.. It would be really good if you can ask your colleague to write an answer here in her/his free time.. I am looking forward for something like that..

Comment: Here is something he once wrote http://www.maths.adelaide.edu.au/thomas.leistner/talks/igaworkshop09.pdf